# Why does PyDev flag one variable undefined instance, but not the other?

Tags: pydev

I'm getting started with PyDev but am having trouble understanding its code validation.

For example, in a file containing just the code below, PyDev warns "Unused variable i" in the third line, but has no issue with j in the first line.

```
l1 = ['a' for j in range(10)]
def test():
    l2 = ['a' for i in range(10)]
```

What is triggering PyDev's warning in this example?
(I know to avoid it by adding # @UnusedVariable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference here is that in the first case you're creating global variables and in the second a local variable (global variables created are not reported because they may be used by another module).

You may add an underline (`_`) in front of the variable (i.e.: `_i`) to signal that you know it is not used and shouldn't be reported.